# Multiple parameter in Row Filter

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to put a textbox as an Rowfilter under a textchanged event !

The code below is used to GRID to get the appropriate `Reg_Number` **or** `Customer_Name` which is entered in the text box!

wat's the surprising fact is, this code directly takes the 2nd Argument

(i.e)
`((DataTable)radGridView1.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = "Reg_Number like '%" + radTextBoxControl1.Text + "%'";`

tried to switch the lines, but no matter what i did, it ignores the 1st one and takes the 2nd

i tried to put AND to get both in a single line, bt din't work, plz hel me frnzz!

```
private void radTextBoxControl1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ((DataTable)radGridView1.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter =
            "Customer_Name like '%" + radTextBoxControl1.Text + "%'";
        ((DataTable)radGridView1.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter =
            "Reg_Number like '%" + radTextBoxControl1.Text + "%'";
    }
    catch (Exception) { }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because the second assignment replaces the first one

```
myDataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = "firstFilter";
myDataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = "secondFilter";
// Now RowFilter is "secondFilter"
```

You must combine the 2 filters with a logical OR to get results fulfilling both conditions:

```
myDataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = "firstFilter OR secondFilter";
```

---

```
var view = ((DataTable)radGridView1.DataSource).DefaultView;
string escapedText = radTextBoxControl1.Text.Replace("'", "''");
view.RowFilter = "Customer_Name LIKE '%" + escapedText + "%' OR " +
                    "Reg_Number LIKE '%" + escapedText + "%'";
```

It becomes clearer with `String.Format`:

```
view.RowFilter = String.Format("Customer_Name LIKE '%{0}%' OR Reg_Number LIKE '%{0}%'",
                               escapedText);
```

or, since C# 7.0, with string interpolation:

```
view.RowFilter =
    $"Customer_Name LIKE '%{escapedText}%' OR Reg_Number LIKE '%{escapedText}%'";
```

Also, make sure to replace single quotes by two single quotes. This enables the SQL string to contain quotes and prevents SQL-injections:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Name = 'Andy''s Pub';
```

---

The reason you must combine both conditions with `OR`, and not `AND` is, that the user will enter **either** a customer name **or** a registration number (we have only one textbox).

Alternatively, you could check, whether the entry is formatted like a registration number or not and apply the appropriate filter. In pseudo code:

```
if (radTextBoxControl1.Text is formatted as reg_nr) {
    view.RowFilter = "Reg_Number LIKE '%" + escapedText + "%'";
} else {
    view.RowFilter = "Customer_Name LIKE '%" + escapedText + "%'";
}
```

Comment: Wow ! this is a brief example :) Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
((DataTable)radGridView1.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter =
    "Customer_Name like '%" + radTextBoxControl1.Text + "%' AND Reg_Number like '%" + radTextBoxControl1.Text + "%'";
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need OR operation instead of AND `"Customer_Name like '%" + radTextBoxControl1.Text + "%' OR Reg_Number like '%" + radTextBoxControl1.Text + "%'";`