# How to apply two filters in DataView

Tags: c#, filter, datatable, dataview, data-filtering

I am trying to apply two filters in a DataView such that first it should filter items of one column, and then those values should further be filtered by a second column. below is my code, but this code is just filtering both separately.

```
DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
                dv.RowFilter = string.Format("[Animal Id] Like '%{0}%'", comboBox6.Text.Trim());
                dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Step Like '%{0}%'", comboBox5.Text.Trim());
```

Comment: Can you provide us more information about the data structure and how you set up the 'dt' object?

Comment: This answers your question: [Multiple parameter in Row Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15186375/multiple-parameter-in-row-filter).  Simple to find the 8 yr old post using the search criteria *c# multiple rowfilters*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this code is just filtering both separately.

That's because the second filter overwrites the first. You appear to be saying you want an AND situation

```
dv.RowFilter = string.Format("[Animal Id] Like '%{0}%' AND [Step] Like '%{1}%'", comboBox6.Text.Trim(), comboBox5.Text.Trim());
```

Please rename your controls to something better than textBox27, label35. Renaming controls takes seconds costs nothing and brings immense value that anyone who reads the code has a chance at understanding it, especially if theyre on e.g. the internet and cannot swap back to the form constantly to see whether the first name is in textBox45, or textBox22

Comment: Hi Thanks, this worked

Comment: And yes, will keep in mind your comment about the renaming of controls